# how to make time.sleep() ignore end=""

Tags: python, sleep

I have been trying to make a part of a program that will print a . every second (like a loading thing for fun). However, end= has been making it not print till the sleep completes. I've looked everywhere, but I can't find it. Is there a way around it?

```
for x in range(1, 3):
  print(".", end="")
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: *"I've looked everywhere"* - Have you looked at the documentation of the print function?

Comment: There's almost certainly a duplicate of this, but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: @Barmar Found one! *"If you are having trouble with buffering, you can flush the output by adding `flush=True`"*

Comment: Yes, here we go; per the docs  “The file argument must be an object with a write(string) method; if it is not present or None, sys.stdout will be used.”; “When interactive, **the stdout stream is line-buffered.**”; and “Output buffering is usually determined by file. However, if flush is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.”

Comment: What you are missing is that print writes strings to a buffer. The strings are sent to the output only when the buffer is full or when the buffer is flushed, as in when the execution of the code concludes and the process is about to exit.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
flush=True
```

argument.

Your code will be:

```
for x in range(1, 3):
    print(".", end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```